# Four equations with three variables!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I have these four equations:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
A_1 = A_c -D \theta cos(\phi)\\ 
A_2 = A_c -D \theta cos(\phi-\pi/2)\\ 
A_3 = A_c -D \theta cos(\phi-\pi)\\ 
A_4 = A_c -D \theta cos(\phi-3\pi/2)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Variables $A_1$ to $A_4$ are given, D is a constant, and Variables $A_c$, $\theta$, and $\phi$ are unknown.

I need to find $\frac{d \theta}{d A_1}$ to $\frac{d \theta}{d A_4}$, but I have some problems. What I tried was that I used three of these equations and derived $\theta$, $\phi$, and $A_c$, and then differentiated $\theta$ with respect to $A_i$ separately, but I am not sure if this is correct or not.

The thing is that variables $A_i$ are related. This means that if variable $A_1$ changes, at least one of the variables $A_2$ to $A_4$ will also change as there is this relation between the $A_i$ and $A_c$ parameters:

$A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4=4 A_c$

I also get different results when I use three other set of these four equations to derive the parameters. So how can I study the changes of variables $\theta$ and $\phi$ due to changes in variables $A_1$ to $A_4$.

Edit:
If I derive variable $\theta$ from the first three equations listed above, I'll have:
$$\theta=\frac{\sqrt{2}\, \sqrt{{\mathrm{A1}}^2 - 2\, \mathrm{A1}\, \mathrm{A2} + 2\, {\mathrm{A2}}^2 - 2\, \mathrm{A2}\, \mathrm{A3} + {\mathrm{A3}}^2}}{2\, R}$$

and if I derive variable $\theta$ from the first, second and fourth equations, I'll have:

$$\theta=\frac{\sqrt{2}\, \sqrt{2\, {\mathrm{A1}}^2 - 2\, \mathrm{A1}\, \mathrm{A2} - 2\, \mathrm{A1}\, \mathrm{A4} + {\mathrm{A2}}^2 + {\mathrm{A4}}^2}}{2\, R}$$

,and finally I use $\theta$ derived by Ross Millikan in the answer below which is:

$$\theta=\frac{\sqrt{{\left(\mathrm{A1} - \mathrm{A3}\right)}^2 + {\left(\mathrm{A2} - \mathrm{A4}\right)}^2}}{2\, R}$$

As you notice, the first two solutions do not involve all $A_1$ to $A_4$.
All of these solution calculates correct value for $\theta$, but when I differentiate them with respect to $A_1$, you will see different results.

This is how I do this: For $\theta=45 \deg$ and $\phi=0$, I first calculated all $A_1$ to $A_4$ parameters using the four equation in the begining. Now if I use these $A_1$ to $A_4$ parameters in the above solutions for $\theta$, they all would calculate correct $\theta$, but when I differentiate above solutions for $\theta$, and then use $A_1$ to $A_4$ parameters, they determines values of -0.1667, -0.3333, and -0.1667, respectively. And if I repeat this procedure for $\theta=45 \deg$ and $\phi=45 \deg$, then the results would be 0.0, -0.2357, and -0.1179.

My understanding is that the correct one is the third solution that involves all of the $A_1$ to $A_4$ parameters, but then I don't know what is logically wrong with others or how I can relate the two other solutions to the correct one?

Comment: Is $\theta$ a variable or a function of all the other variables? Please tell us what are the functions  (dependent variables) and which are the independent variables.

Comment: Variables $A_i$ are dependants and if variable $A_1$ changes, at least one of the variables $A_2$ to $A_4$ will also change. Variables $\theta$, $\phi$, and $A_c$ are independant and can be changed individually.

Comment: You have missed the point that $A_1+A_3-A_2-A_4=0$  You can use this to eliminate any of the $A$'s that you want, so an expression with only three can be correct.  For the same reason, it doesn't make sense to take $\frac {d\theta}{dA_1}$ without recognizing that (at least) one of the $\frac {dA_i}{dA_1}$'s is non-zero.  For example you can have $\frac {dA_3}{dA_1}=-1$ and you need to use the chain rule wherever you see an $A_3$

Comment: So the correct $\frac{d \theta}{d A_1}$ is: $$\frac{d \theta}{d A_1} = \frac{d \theta}{d A_1} +\frac{d \theta}{d A_2}*\frac{d A_2}{d A_1}+\frac{d \theta}{d A_3}*\frac{d A_3}{d A_1}+\frac{d \theta}{d A_4}*\frac{d A_4}{d A_1}$$ where in this case $\frac{d A_2}{d A_1}$=1, $\frac{d A_3}{d A_1}$=-1, and $\frac{d A_4}{d A_1}$=1, am I right?

Comment: I just realized that $\frac{d A_2}{d A_1}$=0 and also $\frac{d A_4}{d A_1}$=0, and this produces the correct vakue. Now could you please help me on how to find the relation between $A_i$ in case of 5 variables. The only relation between $A_i$ in case of 5 variables is: $$A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4+A_5=5*A_c$$ and I am not sure how to find for example $\frac{d A_2}{d A_1}$ in case of five vars.

Comment: Is this correct from the very top four equations?: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{\mathrm{dA2}}{\mathrm{dA1}} = \frac{\cos\!\left(\mathrm{Phi} - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{\cos\!\left(\mathrm{Phi}\right)}\\ 
\frac{\mathrm{dA3}}{\mathrm{dA1}} = \frac{\cos\!\left(\mathrm{Phi} - \pi\right)}{\cos\!\left(\mathrm{Phi}\right)}\\ 
\frac{\mathrm{dA4}}{\mathrm{dA1}} = \frac{\cos\!\left(\mathrm{Phi} - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{\cos\!\left(\mathrm{Phi}\right)}
\end{matrix}\right.$$ I should say that $A_c$ is the initial value of all $A_i$ parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\cos(\phi-\pi)=-\cos(\phi), \cos(\phi - \pi/2)=\sin(\phi)$ so $A_3=A_c+D\theta \cos(\phi)$ which gives $A_1+A_3=2A_c=A_2+A_4$  If these are not satisfied your equations are contradictory. You can then write $$A_3-A_1=2D\theta \cos(\phi)\\A_4-A_2=2D\theta \sin(\phi)\\ \phi=\arctan\left(\frac {A_4-A_2}{A_3-A_1}\right)\\ \theta=\frac 1{2D}\sqrt{(A_3-A_1)^2+(A_4-A_2)^2}\\ \theta=\frac 1{2D}\sqrt{(2A_c-2A_1)^2+(2A_c-2A_2)^2}$$  If $A_c$ is fixed, you can now take $\frac {d\theta}{dA_1}$ and $\frac {d\theta}{dA_2}$.  The other derivatives are the negatives of these.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is fantastic. But the thing is that I can produce similar type of equations for 5 variables as: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
A_1 = A_c -D \theta cos(\phi)\\ 
A_2 = A_c -D \theta cos(\phi-2 \pi/5)\\ 
A_3 = A_c -D \theta cos(\phi-4 \pi/5)\\ 
A_4 = A_c -D \theta cos(\phi-6 \pi/5)\\A_5 = A_c -D \theta cos(\phi-8 \pi/5)
\end{matrix}\right.$$ Is it possible to derive variables $\theta$ and $\phi$ as functions of $A_1$ to $A_5$?

Comment: This can be extended to 6, 7, 8, ... variables. So I was looking for kind of generic method to derive the differentiations.

Comment: When you have constraints like this, you need to specify how they are maintained.  When $A_1$ increases, what decreases to maintain the sum?  In the four case, we could derive it, but in the other ones you have more freedom.

Comment: So if I use three of these equations and derive $\theta$ and differentiate it with respect to $L_1$. Then try three other equations and derive $\theta$ and its differentiation with respect to $L_1$, will I get same results? The values of $\theta$ derived using any three of the equations are similar, but I am not sure about differentiation of them!

Comment: Can you join in chat?  I think I have given you write access at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12030/four-equations-with-three-variables

Comment: For more variables you will have two constraint equations, basically one coming from each of the sine and cosine terms when you expand the trig functions. As you change A1 you need to change (some of) the other A's to keep the constraints satisfied. Once you specify how you are doing that, you can roll it into the derivatives.  In the six equation case, you again have "opposite vectors", so you could make $\Delta A_1=-\Delta A_4$ and their derivatives would then be negatives. But you could also compensate for changes to A1 by using A3,A5. What you can't do is change A1 all by itself

Comment: I tried, but since I don't have enough reputation, I can't! What you are saying is exactly true and I can feel it, but then does it mean that, since I can not change $A_1$ by itself, then I can not find diff(\theta,A_1) and such thing does not exists?

Comment: For four variables, I used you derivation for $\theta$ and compared it with the case that I used three first equations and derived $\theta$. The value of $\theta$ using both of these methhods are exactly same, but the value of differentiations are totally different! Do you have any explanation for this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean the value of differentiations are different.  What values do you get?

Comment: I just edited the main post and tried to make it clearer.